# Grep OR Operator Not Working

Tags: unix, grep, operator-keyword

I need help with Unix.
I am trying to see if one of two statements (printf and fprintf) are in a file. I used the command:

```
search=`cat $file | grep -w "fprintf\|printf"`
```

For some reason, it doesn't find either in files where one of those two exists. Why?

Comment: Why don't you drop the word regexp flag, `-w`?

Comment: [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) — Please note that you should be using `search=$(grep -w -E -e "f?printf" $file)` or something similar rather than wasting time with `cat` and a pipe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, [standard `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) doesn't support the `|` operator.  You need to use `egrep` or the `-E` flag.

Second, inside double-quotes, `\|` means `\|`.  The backslash gets passed through to the `grep` command, so even if `grep` understood the `|` operator, the backslash would turn it into a normal character.

Try this:

```
search=`cat $file | egrep -w "fprintf|printf"`
```

Or you can provide each alternative as a separate argument to `grep`:

```
search=`cat $file | grep -w -e fprintf -e printf
```

Comment: GNU grep supports it just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still really new to Unix.

Comment: If he were using GNU grep, his command would have matched.  Standard `grep` does not treat `\|` the way `egrep` treats `|`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -w "fprintf\|printf" $file
```

This works fine in my shell. Still, here are some alternatives:

```
egrep -w 'fprintf|printf' $file
grep -wE 'fprintf|printf' $file
grep -we 'fprintf\|printf' $file
```